# Adding user time in python 3

Tags: python, time, addition

Hi Everyone i have googles to my hearts content but have not found the answer. 
Basically I want to add user inputted time to the current time.
This is just a small project I'm working on while learning Python.
So if the current time is `17:16` and the user wants to add `1hr 30` to that. how would i do it.
This is what i have:

```
import datetime

flex = input("Enter your flex amount in HHMM:")

flex = flex[0]+flex[1]+"-"+flex[2]+flex[3]

time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M")

balance = time+flex

print(time)
print(flex)
print(balance)
```

I have now tried

```
import datetime

flex = input("Enter your flex amount in HHMM:")
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M")

flex = flex[0]+flex[1]+"-"+flex[2]+flex[3]
time = time[0]+time[1]+"-"+time[2]+time[3]

balance = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(time[0]+time[1]), 
minutes=int(time[2]+time[3]) + 
datetime.timedelta(hours=int(flex[0]+flex[1]), 
minutes=int(flex[2]+flex[3]))
```

But now its complaining about its expecting an integer. but if i change it ot an integer will that not defeat the purpose of me wanting to add is as time.

Thanks

I got it to work using the answer. This is what it looks like now thanks pal.

```
from datetime import timedelta as td
import datetime as da

#flex = input("Enter your flex amount in HHMM:")
flex = "0134"
now = da.datetime.now()
user_hours = int(flex[:2])
user_minute = int(flex[2:5])
delay = td(hours=user_hours, minutes=user_minute)

balance = da.datetime.now()+delay

print("Lunch: " +str(lunch))
print("Time when balance at 00:00 : " +str(balance))
print("Now: " +str(now))
```

Comment: Use `timedelta`

Comment: If you Google the phrase "Python add time", you’ll find resources that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: I have tried that but i feel that me not knowing how python expects these values is causing me to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple using [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) create an offset indicated by timedelta object and ad it to your time object (working the same with date and datetime too).

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

actual_time = datetime.now()
user_hours = int(flex[:3])
user_minute = int(flex[2:5])
delay = timedelta(hours=user_hours, minutes=user_minute)

print(datetime.now()+delay)
```

Comment: So with your recommendation im getting:        
 Unexpected argument(s) Possible callees: timedelta(self: timedelta, days: float=..., seconds: float=..., microseconds: float=..., milliseconds: float=..., minutes: float=..., hours: float=..., weeks: float=..., *, fold: int=...) timedelta(self: timedelta, days: float=..., seconds: float=..., microseconds: float=..., milliseconds: float=..., minutes: float=..., hours: float=..., weeks: float=...)

Comment: I'm not sure why this happened, I have tried it with `flex="2103"` and worked. If you want try to explain how you used my code when this error happened. So we can understand what was the problem and have some references for future situations.

Answer (score 0):

> *So if the current time is 17:16 and the user wants to add 1hr 30 to
>   that. how would i do it.*

---

You can use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta), i.e.:

```
new_time = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=1, minutes=30) # or simply minutes=90, etc...
```

Comment: Got to revise your code that is concat a string to timedelta

Answer (score 0):

Cool so when tring

balance = datetime.timedelta(hours=int(time[0]+time[1]), minutes=int(time[2]+time[3]) + datetime.timedelta(hours=int(flex[0]+flex[1]), minutes=int(flex[2]+flex[3]))

its complaining that its expecting an interger not a time delta

Comment: You forgot a parenthesis ")" after `(..minutes=int(time[2]+time[3])` so when the interpreter looks here it sees another + and tries to add something, but it's correctly expecting something that can be considered an integer (like float and so on). However, timedelta is an object and Python doesn't know how to combine the two in one integer to assign it on minutes that expects a number. In short you forgot to correctly close timedelta call leading to this error.